# Golang DRY for nested structs

Tags: go, struct, dry

I have a BaseEntity struct and one method with *BaseEntity receiver that parses xml from file

```
type BaseEntity struct {
   FilePath   string
   Collection string
}

func (this *BaseEntity) Parse() *[]byte {
    xmlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(this.FilePath)
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
       return nil
    }
    return &xmlFile
}
```

I also have several structs where BaseEntity is embedded, for eg. Users, Posts, Comments, Tags ... etc

```
type Users struct {
    Data []User `xml:"row"`
    BaseEntity
}
type User struct {
    WebsiteUrl      string `xml:"WebsiteUrl,attr"`
    UpVotes         string `xml:"UpVotes,attr"`
    Id              string `xml:"Id,attr"`
    Age             string `xml:"Age,attr"`
    DisplayName     string `xml:"DisplayName,attr"`
    AboutMe         string `xml:"AboutMe,attr"`
    Reputation      string `xml:"Reputation,attr"`
    LastAccessDate  string `xml:"LastAccessDate,attr"`
    DownVotes       string `xml:"DownVotes,attr"`
    AccountId       string `xml:"AccountId,attr"`
    Location        string `xml:"Location,attr"`
    Views           string `xml:"Views,attr"`
    CreationDate    string `xml:"CreationDate,attr"`
    ProfileImageUrl string `xml:"ProfileImageUrl,attr"`
}

func (this *Users) LoadDataToDB() {

    file := this.Parse()
    xml.Unmarshal(*file, &this)

    // Init db
    db := database.MgoDb{}
    db.Init()
    defer db.Close()

    for _, row := range this.Data {
        err := db.C(this.Collection).Insert(&row)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

And for each of these structs I need to create a method LoadDataToDB that loads data in db and has some code.

This method can't have *BaseEntity receiver because I can't get this.Data in base struct and I can't get this struct from parameters because it always a different struct.

How to DRY and move this repeating method from every embedded struct to one?

Comment: In this code `User` is not embedding `BaseStruct`. So I'm confused.

Comment: Using `this` as pointer receiver is not recommended style. Create a datastore object with a Put(v interface{}) method and use reflect to determine runtime type of object being put.

Comment: So if I use reflect for this, my method should know every type what I need to process?

Comment: Not necessarily. The method will load try to load into db whatever you pass it - it'll throw an error if what you're trying to do isn't permitted.

Comment: ok, but if I use `interface{}` how my method should know that my struct have `Data` field? So i need `for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ ` do `if val.Type().Name() == "Data"` then  `data := val.Field(i).Interface()` ?

Comment: And it gave me `importers/base.go:40: cannot range over data (type interface {})` when I try to `for _, row := range data`

Comment: I think you can accomplish what you want to do without knowing the names of the fields. There are other functions in reflect which you could try instead of ranging over the interface - relect.ValueOf(data).Slice(...) for instance.

Comment: Please simplify your code snippet. It is complicated with redundant details of implementation. I believe you will find an answer when you try to reproduce the issue with simpler and shorter code snippet.